# AWS VPC Peering Connection Not Working

Tags: networking, amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc

I've set up a VPC peering connection between two of my VPCs, but they can't ping or even find each other for some reason. I allowed them to talk to each other in the security rules.

Any idea if I'm missing anything here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you followed a guide, such as [this one](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/peering/working-with-vpc-peering.html)?

- Create VPC peering connection
- Accept connection
- Update route table
- Update security groups

Based on your question I suspect you haven't updated your route tables.

If you have done all this please update your question with much more detail - exactly what you've done, screenshots of relevant parts of the console, and a ping demonstrating that the connectivity to a working instance doesn't work.

Comment: oh damn, i didnt know i hadto update the route table. i did and it worked!
thanks alot!

Comment: Welcome - routing is fairly key inside a VPC